# Spree with Payupaisa Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, spree-paypal-express

I want to add Payupaisa gateway for my shopping cart site. I use spree. I used gem

```
gem 'spree_payupaisa', :github => "meetdestiny/spree_payupaisa_express", :branch => "2-1-stable"

https://github.com/meetdestiny/spree_payupaisa_express
```

but it give error while I am updating bundle

```
Git error: command `git rev-parse 2-1-stable` in directory
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@demo/cache/bundler/git/spree_payupaisa_express-6aebc199a8cbc824377ffe9416c892e73cc3271e has failed.
```

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions on that repository are incorrect.  That git repository doesn't have a 2-1-stable branch.  Try the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_payupaisa', :github => "meetdestiny/spree_payupaisa_express"
```

Which should currently work with Spree 2.1.

You should file an issue/pull request on the repository to correct the instructions.

Comment: Again I got error like

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'spree_payupaisa (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/meetdestiny/spree_payupaisa_express.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'spree_payupaisa (>= 0) ruby'

Comment: Try gem 'spree_payupaisa_express', :github => "meetdestiny/spree_payupaisa_express"

Comment: same thing again

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_payupaisa_express (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (~> 2.1.1) ruby

    spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (2.2.0.beta)